# Hosting a website on multiple ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I am Kind of new to AWS and I have a simple question. I am planning to host a website on 2 ec2 instances for example or more. I know that I need to use Route 53 to point to my load balancer and then the load balancer should distribute load on ec2 instances. Now do I need to setup apache, php and mysqli on each instance?

thanks

Comment: I think you should try asking on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: thanks, I will try there

Comment: Do you really need a sophisticated load balancing? Why cant you use Route53's built-in load balancing (DNS balancing)?

Comment: No I dont need sophisticated load balancer but I wanted to know how to do it with load balancer